# Yii internationalization(i18n)

Tags: yii

```
Yii internationalization(i18n)
protected/config/main.php
'language' => 'en_us',
protected/views/site/index.php

<?php
echo Yii::t('test','user');
```

The translated file should be created in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Yii site (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n#locale-and-language)

Info: Yii comes with locale data for nearly every language and region. The data is obtained from Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR). For each locale, only a subset of the CLDR data is provided as the original data contains a lot of rarely used information. Users can also supply their own customized locale data. To do so, configure the CApplication::localeDataPath property with the directory that contains the customized locale data. Please refer to the locale data files under framework/i18n/data in order to create customized locale data files.